# Good alternative to original Dell Latitude E5400 battery (India)

Tags: laptop, power-supply

I'm looking to buy a new battery online for my Dell Latitude E5400 laptop. I don't want to spend on an original one because it is ridiculously expensive and I especially don't want to spend that much for an ancient laptop.

Looking forward for some good suggestions from the knowledgeable ones.

Please suggest brands that are available to buy in India. I found some brands like - Lapguard, ARB and Gizga. Any reviews on them from users are more than welcome.